# Couchbase N1QL Syntax error on simpLe JOIN

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a simple JSON Document with Countries:

Doc ID **Countries**

```
{
  "type": "countries",
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Argentina",
      "code": "AR"
    },
    {
      "name": "Armenia",
      "code": "AM"
    }
]}
```

Doc ID: **CarSample**

```
{
  "countryCode": "AR",
  "brand": "Mercedez",
  "type": "car"
}
```

Now I am trying to make a simple join between these 2:

```
SELECT * FROM BucketName AS Countries 
   JOIN BucketName AS cars ON Countries.countries[0].code=cars.countryCode 
WHERE cars.type="car" AND Countries.type="countries";
```

I ran them with **cbq** and WebConsole both triggers

a Syntax error. On VERSION 5.1 of Couchbase

I created different type of index but no change on the result.

Can you please help me understand what is wrong it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANSI JOINS are supported only in CB 5.50](https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/)

[Pre CB 5.50 supports LOOKUP and Index Joins](https://dzone.com/articles/visually-explaining-n1ql-joins)